# Shell command with redirect to file

Tags: vb.net

I try to run program with some parametrs and then redirect output to file. But redirecting is not work. If the file.txt does not exist then, I get error with "file not found" in cmd window. If the file exist, redirecting is not work.

```
Dim comstr As String = TextBox1.Text + " -p1 -p2 -p3 """ + TextBox2.Text + """>file.txt"
Shell(comstr, AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
```

Comment: The output redirection is a `cmd.exe` feature. E.g., it work if you execute the command inside the `cmd.exe` console. You could use `System.Diagnostics.Process` and its `ProcessStartInfo` `.FileName` and `.Argument` properties to setup the command. Use `.RedirectStandardOutput` to redirect the command output to a `Stream` you have initialized beforehand.

Comment: Another option is to execute `cmd.exe /c` or `/k` and pass that string as command. But you should read the remarks section of [Interaction.Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.shell?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Shell);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2)) before making this decision.

Comment: Thank you, Jimi!